# find last occurence of multiple characters in a string in Python

Tags: python, string

I would like to find the last occurrence of a number of characters in a string.

str.rfind() will give the index of the last occurrence of a single character in a string, but I need the index of the last occurrence of any of a number of characters. For example if I had a string:

```
test_string = '([2+2])-[3+4])'
```

I would want a function that returns the index of the last occurence of {, [, or { similar to

```
test_string.rfind('(', '[', '{')
```

Which would ideally return 8. What is the best way to do this?

```
max(test_string.rfind('('), test_string.rfind('['), test_string.rfind('{'))
```

seems clunky and not Pythonic.

Comment: I don't like where this question is going.... are you trying to write a math parser using this type of character matching? You should use [`pyparsing`](https://pythonhosted.org//pyparsing/) it is a far more robust library for parsing strings with arbitrarily nested enclosing character pairs

Comment: You could use a regex to find one of those characters with as much as possible before that: `re.match(r".*[\(\[\}]", test_string).end() - 1` Not pretty, but seems to work.

Comment: `max(map(test_string.rfind,'([{'))`

Comment: @CoryKramer yes this is for math parsing. In normal circumstances I would use pyparsing, but I'm doing this more for educational purposes and trying to implement something on my own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use generator expression to do this in a Pythonic way.

```
max(test_string.rfind(i) for i in "([{")
```

This iterates through the list/tuple of characters that you want to check and uses [`rfind()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rfind) on them, groups those values together, and then returns the maximum value.

Comment: you have a typo (one extra `)`)

Comment: `'([{'` is a shorter alternative for `('(', '[', '{')`.

Comment: what happens when none of the keys is found in the string?  explain it in the answer, it would be helpful

Comment: @Pynchia Thanks, that was because I copy/pasted carelessly (had an extra `)` from a `print` statement)

Comment: @Pynchia: rfind returns -1 if the needle isn't found, and the max of three -1s would still be -1.

Comment: yes, ok. mine was just a suggestion to explain how to use the solution. An excellent one. Upvoted

Comment: That is a generator expression not a list comp

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ahh, I knew something seemed off. I still don't have a great understanding of generators, but this definitely isn't list comp. Thanks :)

Comment: if you see `(for i ...)` you have a gen exp, a list comp has `[]`

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty concise, and will do the trick.

```
max(map(test_string.rfind, '([{'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reversed to start at the end of the string getting the first match, using the length of the  string -1 - the index `i` to get the index counting from the start, doing at worst a single pass over the string:

```
test_string = '([2+2])-[3+4])'
st = {"[", "(", "{"}
print(next((len(test_string) - 1 - i 
            for i, s in enumerate(reversed(test_string)) if s in st),-1))
8
```

If there is no match, you will get `-1` as the default value. This is a lot more efficient if you a large amount of substrings to search for than doing an `O(n)` rfind for every substring you want to match and then getting the max of all those

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def last_of_many(string, findees):
...     return max(string.rfind(s) for s in findees)
... 
>>> test_string = '([2+2])-[3+4])'
>>> last_of_many(test_string, '([{')
8
>>> last_of_many(test_string, ['+4', '+2'])
10
>>>
```